# access html input in real time an display in html-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two inputs, the one should contain the firstname and the other one the lastname of a new user. Now i want to display the username (firstname.lastname) on real time in a . But when i edit the second input, the whole text in the  changes.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/qun74mwc/13/

HTML:

```
<span id="username"></span><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" />
```

Jquery:

```
var $username = $("#username");

$("input[name='firstname']").keyup(function() {
   $("#username").text( this.value + ".");
});

$("input[name='lastname']").keyup(function() {
   $("#username").text( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.text( this.value )
```

You *replace* what's in the `span` with the *current input's* value.  Instead, replace it with the entire calculated value.  For which you need only one `keyup` handler at all:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var formattedName = $("input[name='firstname']").val() + "." + $("input[name='lastname']").val();
    $("#username").text(formattedName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot.

Comment: Kudos for explaining the actual problem and not just the solution.

Answer (score 3):

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qun74mwc/24/)

```js
$("input[name='firstname'], input[name='lastname']").keyup(function() {
 var $fnVal = $("input[name='firstname']").val(),
   $lnVal = $("input[name='lastname']").val();
  
  $("#username").text( $fnVal + "." + $lnVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="username"></span><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd tackle it: https://jsfiddle.net/benhull/qun74mwc/23/

```
function updateText(){
    $("#username").text( $("input[name='firstname']").val() + "." + $("input[name='lastname']").val() );
}

$("input[name='firstname']").keyup(updateText);
$("input[name='lastname']").keyup(updateText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Give ids to the input fields (ex. same as their names) and then edit your js to:

```
var $username = $("#username");

$("input[name='firstname']").keyup(function() {
    $("#username").text( this.value + "." + $('#lastname').val());
});

$("input[name='lastname']").keyup(function() {
    $("#username").text($('#firstname').val() + "." + this.value );
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/qun74mwc/25/

Answer (score 1):

**Style Note:** This will make your code a lot more professional and stop autocomplete from spamming mobile users by zooming in users to the point they can't even see what they type in the form fields, plus remember to take note of the previous posts in order to form what you are looking for.

Make sure to style your HTML input side to something like this:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  First Name:<br><input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
  Last Name:<br><input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
</form>
```

OR

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  First Name:<br><input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last Name:<br><input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
</form>
```

You can also use a CDN for loading jQuery without having to download it directly such as:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use variables.

```
var $username = $("#username");
var firstName = '';
var lastName = '';

$("input[name='firstname']").keyup(function() {
  firstName = this.value;
  renderUsernameSpan();
});

$("input[name='lastname']").keyup(function() {
  lastName = this.value;
  renderUsernameSpan();
});

function renderUsernameSpan(){
        $("#username").text( firstName + '.' + lastName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, this is what you want I think

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


first name : <input type="text" id="firstname">
last name :<input type="text" id="lasttname">

<h3 class="display"></h3>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#firstname, #lasttname").on('keyup keydown',function(){
      $(".display").text("");

      var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
      var lasttname = $("#lasttname").val();
      var fullname = firstname+"."+ lasttname;
      //alert(fullname);
      $(".display").append(fullname);
   });
});

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **I just changed you code a lil**

```
var $username = $("#username");
var fn = ""
var ln = ""
$("input[name='firstname']").keyup(function() {
    fn = this.value + "."
    $("#username").text( fn + ln );
});

$("input[name='lastname']").keyup(function() {
    ln = this.value;
    $("#username").text(  fn + ln );
});
```

[Your code UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/qun74mwc/26/)